# how to feed DNNClassifier with numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I'm trying to create a DNNClassifier but i don't know how to pass my data into the object.My data files are .npy files created with np.save().

- Training data: an array of shape (106398,338) where 106398 is the number of instances of data.
- Training labels: an array of shape (106398,97) where 97 is the number of classes that i want to predict (in hot encoding)

---

```
import tensorflow as tf
from  tensorflow.contrib.learn import DNNClassifier
import numpy as np

feature_columns = np.load(path_to_file)#learn.infer_real_valued_columns_from_input(iris.data)
feature_tags=np.load(path_to_other_file)

classifier = DNNClassifier(hidden_units=[10, 20, 10], n_classes=97, feature_columns=feature_columns)
classifier.fit(feature_columns, feature_tags, steps=200, batch_size=1000)

predictions = list(classifier.predict(feature_columns, as_iterable=True))
score = metrics.accuracy_score(feature_tags, predictions)

print("Accuracy: %f" % score)
```

and i get: ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

I've tried to make both(feature_columns and feature_tags) into tf.constant bot it don't work.

How can i fix it?

---

```
8.0 locally Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "nueva.py", line 31, 
    in <module> classifier = DNNClassifier(hidden_units=[10, 20, 10], n_classes=97, feature_columns=feature_columns) 
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/l‌​earn/python/learn/es‌​timators/dnn.py", line 296, 
    in init self._feature_columns = tuple(feature_columns or []) 
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Answer (score 1):

If look at other SO questions about that `ValueError..` you'll that this arises when you try to do some sort True/False test on an array.

```
if X>0:....
```

produces this error if `X` is a multielement array.  `X>0` is then an array of True/False values.  That's ambiguous.

Having identified the basic issue, we then need to find where you are doing that sort of test.

Another thing - when reporting an error, also report on the stack - **Where exactly does this error occur?**

Looking at your code, I don't see any test that could trigger this error.  That means it is happening deep inside one of the functions that you call.  **Which?**

I'm guessing that one of function arguments has the wrong form, shape or type.

---

The error is in the `tuple(feature_columns or [])` expression.  Your `feature_columns` parameter should not be an array.  Check the documentation.

From that expression, I'm guessing that `feature_columns` should a default `None`, or a list like `[1,2,3]`:

```
In [110]: [1,2,3] or []
Out[110]: [1, 2, 3]
In [111]: None or []
Out[111]: []
In [112]: np.array([1,2,3]) or []
....
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
In [113]:
```

Comment: It happens in the line where the classifier is created.

Comment: What's the shape and dtype of `feature_columns`?  We also need the error stack.

Comment: the complete error stack is :
    8.0 locally
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nueva.py", line 31, in <module>
    classifier = DNNClassifier(hidden_units=[10, 20, 10], n_classes=97, feature_columns=feature_columns)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/dnn.py", line 296, in __init__
    self._feature_columns = tuple(feature_columns or [])
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

and the shape of feature_columns is (106398,338)  and is an array of floats.

Comment: See my edit. The stack trace is harder to read in a comment, but there's enough to suggest the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use a function `learn.infer_real_valued_columns_from_input` to create `feature_columns` from the numpy array. The following solution works for me:

```
X = np.load(path_to_file)
feature_columns = tf.contrib.learn.infer_real_valued_columns_from_input(X)
classifier = DNNClassifier(hidden_units=[10, 20, 10], n_classes=97, feature_columns=feature_columns)
```

Comment: Isn't it deprecated?